# Show datatips in a logarithmically scaled uiaxes

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, logarithm, datatip

I have encountered a problem using the new `uiaxes` object: after plotting my data, I can click on the data points then it will show a datatips displaying the X and Y data.
When I change the scale of my X axis into a logarithmic one datatips won't display.

I am using MATLAB 2019a.

Here is a sample code :

```
h = uiaxes;
h.XScale = 'log';
a = plot( 1 : 10 );
```

By changing the scale back to linear, the datatips would display correctly again.

I also tried the below command in order to enable the datatips, it works but I have a ton of warnings on my command window saying an error occurred in the `WindowMouseMotion` Callback.

```
cursorMode = datacursormode(h.Parent);
cursorMode.Enable = 'on'
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```matlab
function [] = q56982381()
hF = uifigure(); hAx = uiaxes(hF);
hAx.XScale = 'log';
hP = plot( hAx, 1 : 10 );

% Invoke the datacursor manager:
dcm_obj = datacursormode(hF);
hTip = dcm_obj.createDatatip(hP); % Don't specify any further inputs at this stage

% Wait until the figure loaded:
drawnow; pause(0.1); % or mlapptools.waitForFigureReady(hF); (see note at the bottom)

% Modify the datatip position:
hTip.Position = [2, 2, 0];
```

Results in:

[image]

The [`mlapptools`](https://github.com/StackOverflowMATLABchat/mlapptools) utility, which I co-authored, is meant to help work with and customize UIFigures.